# ping multiple ip and save it to one file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ping

I want to ping several IPs with my linux server, namely:

- ip 10.0.0.1 which is the host connected to the interface swp1
- ip 10.0.0.2 which is the host connected to the interface swp2

with ip source 10.0.0.3 then the results are stored in a file. This command is executed through ansible with the following task:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: VERIFICATION // CONNECTIVITY BY PING
      shell: ping {{ item }} -c 2 -s 10.0.0.3 | grep -i received | awk '{print $4}'
      register: ping
      loop:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 10.0.0.2

  - copy:
      content: "{{ ping.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n') }}"
      dest: ping.txt
```

and the contents of the ping.txt as follows:

```
2
0
```

This task was executed successfully, but, how do I add the connected interface of the pinged host, so that the ping.txt become:

```
swp1 : 2
swp2 : 0
```

What script can be added to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

```
Does this help? I needed to remove the "-s 10.0.0.3" from mine but updated and commented out the link in the playbook below. My -s is not the same I would image as it is for your OS.
```

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: VERIFICATION // CONNECTIVITY BY PING
      #shell: ping {{ item.ip }} -c 2 -s 10.0.0.3 | grep -i received | awk '{print "{{item.name}}:"$4}'
      shell: ping {{ item.ip }} -c 2 | grep -i received | awk '{print "{{item.name}}:"$4}'
      register: ping
      loop:
      - { ip: '10.0.0.1', name: 'swp1'}
      - { ip: '10.0.0.2', name: 'swp2'}

    - copy:
        content: "{{ ping.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n') }}"
        dest: ping.txt
```

```
My ping.txt:
swp1:2
swp2:0
```

```
You can adjust the spacing within the "awk" command to get "swp1 : 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces of an node are accessible in the `ansible_facts` of the host.
Each interface has an entry with its name being a property of the `ansible_facts` dictionary and a list of all the existing interfaces can be accessed under `ansible_facts.interfaces`.

Also, the item used to create a result from a loop in a registered command can be accessed via the `item` property of the dictionaries under the `results` list.

So, you can create an intermediary fact in order to find back the name of the interface based on its IP before dumping the result to a file.

Here would be the resulting fact and `copy` tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    ping_results: >-
      {{
        ping_results | default([]) + [
          (
            _interfaces_ip | zip(_interfaces_names) 
            | selectattr("0", "eq", item.item) 
            | first
          ).1
          ~ ' : ' 
          ~ item.stdout
        ]
      }}
  loop: "{{ ping.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"
  vars:
    _interfaces: >-
      {{
        ansible_facts 
        | dict2items 
        | selectattr('key', 'in', ansible_facts.interfaces) 
      }}
    _interfaces_names: >-
      {{
        _interfaces
        | map(attribute="key")
      }}
    _interfaces_ip: >-
      {{
        _interfaces
        | map(attribute="value.ipv4.address", default="n/a")
      }}

- copy:
    content: "{{ ping_results | join('\n') }}"
    dest: ping.txt
```

Your modified playbook, should then, yield, in your case:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [VERIFICATION // CONNECTIVITY BY PING] ******************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.0.0.1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.0.0.2)

TASK [copy] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

And your *ping.txt* would contains:

```
swp1 : 2
swp2 : 0
```